# In Python, how to write a file on a remote machine synchronously?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, fsync

Now I need to open a remote file to write something, the code just like this:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(myHost,myPort,myUser,myPassword)
sftp = client.open_sftp()
fileObject = sftp.open(fullFilePath,'wb')
for i in xrange(10000):
   fileObject.write(databuf)
fileObject.close()
```

Now I want to make sure that all data is actually write into disk
so the code is modified as follow:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(myHost,myPort,myUser,myPassword)
sftp = client.open_sftp()
fileObject = sftp.open(fullFilePath,'wb')
for i in xrange(10000):
   fileObject.write(databuf)
   fileObject.flush()
   os.fsync(fileObject.fileno())
fileObject.close()
```

But the message is showed:

```
  AttributeError: 'SFTPFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

If I  want to force write of file to disk synchronously,
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile

SFTPFile doesn't have the method you are trying to call. The only methods available are the following:

```
check(hash_algorithm, offset=0, length=0, block_size=0)
chmod(mode)
chown(uid, gid)
close()
flush()
gettimeout()
next()
prefetch()
read(size=None)
readline(size=None)
readlines(sizehint=None)
readv(chunks)
set_pipelined(pipelined=True)
setblocking(blocking)
settimeout(timeout)
stat()
tell()
truncate(size)
utime(times)
write(data)
writelines(sequence)
xreadlines()
```

The `file.fileno()` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.fileno) is only callable from python file streams, and your `sftp.open()` isn't returning the same type of object as a `file.open()`.

> If I want to force write of file to disk immediately, What can I do?

If I'm reading this right, I'd say you would want to read, or readlines, and then write it to a separate python file object that you would manipulate on the machine you're on, and then write it back to a SFTPFile to go through the proper operations to post back to the server.

Comment: sorry, I mean I want to ask 'If I want to force write of file to disk synchronously, What can I do?'

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand, you mean to the disk and to your server file at the same time?

Comment: I want to make sure all data is write to remote machine's disk, not the remote machine's cache

Answer (score 1):

os.fsync() would not write the file to disk on a remote machine.  os module can only effect what the local machine does.  If you can issue a remote command which would sync the file on the remote machine, then you can issue it after "fileObject.flush()".  Something like this (and this is direct copy and paste from paramico docs [http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/agent.html][1]):

```
session = client.get_transport().open_session()
# Forward local agent
AgentRequestHandler(session)
# Commands executed after this point will see the forwarded agent on
# the remote end.
session.exec_command("YOU SYNC COMMAND, TO BE EXECUTED REMOTELY, HERE")
```